# How to get the last 10 courses based on lectures watched? - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have courses that have modules, the modules have lectures and the lectures only have a relationship to the course through the module. I'm building a feature to continue watching by showing the last 10 courses you watched, clicking on any of these courses then shows you the last watched lecture in that course. I'm saving the pause state of each video and using the updated_at column to determine which lecture was last watched. I'm currently getting 1 last watched course, but I need to get more than one. Here's what I have so far.

```
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $startedLectures = DB::table('lectures')
                ->select('*')
                ->join('watches', 'lectures.id', '=', 'watches.lecture_id')
                ->join('modules', 'lectures.module_id', '=', 'modules.id')
                ->join('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'modules.course_id')
                ->where('watches.user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->where('watches.progress', '!=', '')
                ->where('watches.is_completed', '=', 0)
                ->orderBy('watches.updated_at', 'desc')
                ->limit(10);

        
        $watchedCourses = NULL;

        foreach ($startedLectures as $lecture) {
            $watchedCourses = Course::with('modules.lectures')
                ->where('id', '=', $startedLectures->course_id)
                ->get();
        }
```

Module Model

```
    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'course_id');
    }

    public function lectures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Lecture::class);
    }
    public function getOrderedLectures()
    {
        return $this->lectures()->orderBy('lecture_number', 'asc')->get();
    }
```

Lecture Model

```
    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class,'module_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'watches', 'lecture_id', 'user_id')
            ->withTimestamps()
            ->withPivot(['progress', 'is_completed']);
    }
```

Comment: You're getting 1 watched course because in your `foreach` you're replacing the `$watchedCourses`, you're not adding it to an array

Comment: your query is going to find the last 10 incomplete lectures; if some of those belong to the same course you will get fewer than 10 courses.  you would need a more complex query that groups by course to get the most recent lecture in up to 10 courses